# Find first increasing value in vector

Tags: r, min, self, uniform

I draw a random sample from Uniform Distribution by

```
u <- runif (1000,0,1)
```

Now I want to calculate the value of this random variable

```
N = min_n {n : u_n > u_{n-1}}
```

**Edit**
Let say I draw a random sample of size 10.

So, I have `u= (u_1,u_2,u_3,...,u_10)`. Now I want to find minimum `n` for which `u_n > u_{n-1}`

Comment: Can you please describe in words what your question is?  Right now, it's not clear to me.

Comment: @Andrie Now, I edit my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Try `which(u[-1]>u[-length(u)])[1]`

Comment: @akrun N is always >= 2. But your formula give me N=1 also. Where is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps `which(c(FALSE, u[-1]>u[-length(u)]))[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the difference (using `diff`) then you're looking for where the difference is greater than 0.  We search for the first time that happens

```
u <- c(.5, .4, .3, .6)
min(which(diff(u) > 0))
```

This gives us 3 which is close to what we want but not exactly.  Since this will return 1 if the first difference is greater than 0 what we really want to do is add 1 to the result

```
min(which(diff(u) > 0))) + 1
```

which should give what we want.  This will give a warning if your sequence is strictly descending though since it can't find a value that meets the criteria.  We could code in some tests and decide on the appropriate output in that case but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.